# Conditionally append clicked element to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add an event listener to my unordered list elements with jQuery. When one of the list elements are clicked another unordered list is checked whether it has the clicked element from the former list, more correctly the clone of it, a list element with same text. If the latter list has it nothing happens, however if it does not have it, a copy of it is added to this latter unordered list.

I try to achieve it with `each()` but cannot manage to success the conditional `append()` and the case of starting with an empty `selecteds` list.

I need the latter list, `selecteds`, be empty once.

How can this be achieved?

```js
$("ul#list li").on("click", function(event) {
  var t = $(event.target).text();
  
  if ($("ul#selecteds li").length == 0) {
    $("ul#selecteds").append("<li></li>");
  }
  
  $("ul#selecteds li").each(function(index) {
    var s = $(this).text();
    if (s !== t) {
      console.log("he");
      $(event.target).clone().appendTo($("ul#selecteds"));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="selecteds">
</ul>
<ul id="list">
  <li>asdf</li>
  <li>qwer</li>
  <li>zxcv</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you can't add a clone every time an element in the "selected" list doesn't match.

Also, you don't need to say *e.g.* `ul#selecteds` - `id`s are unique, and sufficient on their own.

```js
$("#list li").on("click", function(event) {
  var t = $(this).text();   // the clicked text

  var exists = false;  // is it already selected?

  $('#selecteds li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == t) {
      exists = true;   // found a match   
      return false;    // stop looking
    }
  });

  // no match? add one
  if (! exists) {
    $('<li>').text(t).appendTo('#selecteds');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="selecteds">
</ul>
<ul id="list">
  <li>asdf</li>
  <li>qwer</li>
  <li>zxcv</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you very much. I see a programming style you have used in this case, not only the answer. To exit when the test yields true.